# smart pointer move semantics unclear to me

Tags: c++, pointers, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Sorry for the generic title but I can only describe what's going on.

```
std::unique_ptr<int> qq() {
    int b = 11;
    std::unique_ptr<int> f(&b);

    return f;
}

int main() {
    std::unique_ptr<int> q = qq();
    int *p = q.release();

    *p = 11;

    std::cout << *p << "\n";

    std::cout << *p << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

outputs

```
11
32767 // why not 11?
```

returning with `return std::move(f)` results in an output of

```
11
0 // why not 11?
```

Comment: Why do you write `std::unique_ptr<int> q(&b);` at all?

Comment: Also, printing `*p` twice and getting different results when you've just assigned to `*p` seems odd; if it doesn't segfault, I'd expect consistent output. Are you sure you didn't print `*q` or `b`?

Comment: @ShadowRanger I edited the code. I forgot to include the function call

Comment: The second example code works for me. Are you sure that's the exact code that segfaults?

Comment: @JamesRoot Your'e right I'm going to delete that until I can reproduce

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're passing around a pointer to stack memory that has become defunct (the stack frame associated with it has unwound, so the variables there are no longer defined/reserved). The function calls involved in output are rewriting it. `unique_ptr` isn't really relevant here, you'd get the same undefined behavior by using:

```
int* qq() {
    int b = 11;
    return &b;
}
```

and avoiding the `unique_ptr` rigmarole, though the simpler version is more likely to be noticed as invalid by the compiler. In both cases, accessing the memory pointed to (`b`'s address) becomes invalid (undefined behavior) the moment the function returns, and in practice, the value of `b` is overwritten by the next function call (in this case, to the `operator<<` overload of `std::cout`).

`unique_ptr` is for dynamically allocated memory, you can't just pass it the address of a stack value and expect it to do anything useful.

Comment: For the record, I see nothing wrong with the second bit of example code; whatever the problem is, it's likely you've obscured it by omitting critical code, and it likely has nothing to do with `unique_ptr`, same as in the case I just explained; you've cloaked simple misuse of pointers in smart pointers, but the misuse of pointers is the problem, not smart pointers themselves.

Comment: You're right about the second example. Still looking into your answer

Comment: I used a simple raw pointer in the return and the compiler did indeed complain that the value escapes local scope. I'll look into how to properly return pointers from functions

Comment: @SephVelut: If the goal is just to dynamically allocate and return a `unique_ptr`, and you're on C++14 or higher, a simple `return std::make_unique<int>(11);` would do the job (in C++14, it should be possible to basically never use `new` or `delete`, using only smart pointers as needed). Just keep it as a `unique_ptr`, don't `release` it (which removes the whole point of `unique_ptr`).